# PowerPivot Data Model Causing Cartesian Product

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerquery, data-analysis, powerpivot

**Summary**

Using a two table PowerPivot data model, I'm not able to create a pivot table that has multiple rows filtered in the same way a single table does using the same columns.

**Details**

I have a simple two table data model:

- Table 1 - Employees
- Table 2 - Office

[image: PowerPivot Data Model]

When I create a pivot table with this model I can list all of the Offices and display the correct value for the number of employees in each office. This works as expected.

[image: Pivot table displaying the two tables merged. Office as a row and employee count as a value.]

**PROBLEM**

When I put a column from each table into the rows field, it does not display the expected result. Instead of listing all of the offices and related employees for each office, it displays all of the employees each time.

[image: Pivot table with OfficeID and EmpID in the row field.]

When I create a table with the Office and Employee data in the same table, I get the expected results.

[image: Third table where the values of Employees and Offices are manually merged into a single table.]

[image: Pivot table showing the desired results]

**Question**

Is it possible to get the same results in a pivot table with two tables in powerpivot that I get with a single table as demonstrated above?
Right now I'm assuming this is either a limitation or I'm missing a setting somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a measure and drop that in a field. The default behaviour is a Cartesian product until you drop a measure in.

[image]

With no measure:

[image]

After adding a measure:

[image]

[image]